# Is there a way to dynamically update WPF localized strings at runtime

Tags: .net, wpf, localization, resources

I would like to maintain a separate resource dictionary for all my strings.  I would like to do this so I can have update the app in production with new string without redeploying the app.  These strings also need to also be localized.

What is the best way to do this in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your deployment constraints are due to corporate standards that introduce significant process constraints to any release.

If you use normal language resources, then you will need to release the language specific resources dll as a minimum.

So you could either,

- implement a whole new way of managing language specific strings and downloading them to the client, (not recommended)
- have some means of downloading the updated resources assemblies to the client,
- just go the extra step and download the whole new client (using click-once or an equivalent)

Personally, I'd consider making my app self updating, so it becomes transparent to the user, and avoids your need not to redeploy (under certain definitions of *deploy*)